# Use a model output as a conditional probability distribution in TensorFlow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, probability

I am implementing a Bayesian network in TensorFlow probability to model interaction between different ML models. Let's assume the models are built as TensorFlow Estimators. The conditional probability of a class given the input data is then simply modelled by the estimator.

Is there a way in TensorFlow probability to wrap the estimator so that I can treat it as a distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have much in the way of direct interop w/ the Estimators API, but you might want to take a look at `tfp.layers`, which contains a collection of Keras `Layers` whose outputs are TFP `Distribution` objects. There are a bunch of pre-defined ones and also a `DistributionLambda` layer, which you can use to construct and output your own `Distribution` instance as, say, the last layer of a Keras `Sequential` model. There are some colabs with nifty examples [here (regression)](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression.ipynb) and [here (variational autoencoder)](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Probabilistic_Layers_VAE.ipynb).

Hope this helps!